# Name for the trivial extension of a single-variable real function to several variables

Tags: functions, reference-request, terminology

This is a question about terminology. Is there any common name for the trivial extension of a real function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to several variables $\tilde{f} \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

By "trivial extension", I mean defining $\tilde{f}$ in terms of $f$ as $\tilde{f}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n))$.

As a simple example, if we have a trigonometric function like $sin(x)$, we can trivially extend it to $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $\sin(x, y, z) = (\sin(x), \sin(y), \sin(z))$. I'm just wondering if there is any accepted name and well-known reference for this simple way of building multivariate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a generally accepted and generally understood term here. You might say $\tilde f$ is the $k$-fold *tensor product* of itself in some space $\bigotimes_1^k V$ of multivariate functions, or use some notation like $f^\otimes$, but you would also have to explain precisely what you mean to the audience.  Which would end up taking more words and notation than simply giving the formula directly.

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to accept this answer (between the two useful ones I received so far), as "tensor product" is probably the closest well-known concept to the idea I had in mind, even though right now I'm dealing with plain n-tuples that don't have a vector space (or algebra or whatever) structure.

Comment: Or you might try "cartesian product", as the graph of your new function is the cartesian product of the graphs of the constituent functions, in a certain sense.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica speaks about "threading a function over lists". It is a built in feature for many standard functions: For example, you get

```
N[Sin[{1,5,-2,4}]]
{0.841471, -0.958924, -0.909297, -0.756802}
```

If you use such a feature for various functions  several times in a paper or talk it pays to invent a special notation.

If $f$ is a given function acting on points $x\in X$ you could denote by $\tilde f$ (or similar) the induced function on $n$-tuples of points, whereby $n$ can be arbitrary, but finite.

Comment: It is more typical in functional programming to call this [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) a function over a list. In Mathematica as well, you can do `Map[Sin, {1, 5, -2, 4}]`.